# Can't handle both click and touch events simultaneously

Tags: android, listeners, ontouchlistener

I am trying to handle touch events and click events on a button. I do the following:

```
button.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
button.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

When any one listener is registered things work fine but when I try to use them both only the touch events are fired. Any workaround? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is a subtle, yet very important difference between the `ClickListener` and the `TouchListener`. The `TouchListener` is executed before the view can respond to the event. The `ClickListener` will receive its event only after the view has handled it.

So when you touch your screen, the `TouchListener` is executed first and when you return `true` for your event, the `ClickListener` will never get it. But if you press the trackball of your device, the `ClickListener` should be fired because the `TouchListener` will not respond to it.

Answer (score 79):

Its a little tricky.

If you set `onTouchListener` you need to return `true` in `ACTION_DOWN`, to tell the system that I have consumed the event and it won't trickle down to other listeners.

But then `OnClickListener` won't be fired.

So you might think, I will just do my thing there and return `false` so I can receive clicks too.
If you do so, it will work, but you won't be subscribed to other upcoming touch events (`ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_UP`)
Therefore, the only option is to return `true` there, but then you won't receive any click events as we said previously.

So you need to perform the click manually in the `ACTION_UP` with `view.performClick()`

This will work.

Comment: The key part of this is "you need to perform the click manually in the ACTION_UP",  thank you sir

Comment: This is really the best answer. In my ACTION_MOVE, I begin intercepting touch events if a certain deltaX threshold is met. If I get to ACTION_UP and that deltaX threshold was never met, I fire `listView.performClick()`, otherwise, I do my swipe actions.

Comment: This obviously should be the answer.

Comment: Great answer. Keep it up

Answer (score 21):

Thanks to @urSus for great answer
But in that case every touch will perform click, Even ACTION_MOVE
Assuming you want to separate `move` event and `click` event you can use a little trick
define a `boolean` field and use like this:

```
 @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
        {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    shouldClick = true;
                    .
                    .
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (shouldClick)
                        view.performClick();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //Do your stuff
                    shouldClick = false;
                    break;
            }
            rootLayout.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Great answer. Keep it up

Comment: perform click is the view method ? or a custom method where we have to perform click

Comment: @user3475052 `performClick()` is every view and its subclasses method

Comment: It works, if `return true;` in MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN branch, remove MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE branch, get movement difference in MotionEvent.ACTION_UP branch. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831395/how-can-i-detect-a-click-in-an-ontouch-listener

Comment: really this answer is best in all similar question

Answer (score 6):

You should return false in your `OnTouchListener` then your `OnClickListener` will be also handled.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you're returning `true` in your `OnTouchListener`? That will consume the event so it won't be sent down for any further processing.

On a side note - what's the point of having both a click and touch listener?

Comment: The client wants a sound to be played when the button is pressed and released, I do it in the 'ACTION_UP' and 'ACTION_DOWN' events. And the click event does the logic. Now I'll have to handle the logic in the touch event itself.

Comment: A button that can be dragged around, then clicked when finished?

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of TouchListener that doesn't shadow ClickListener.

```
import android.graphics.PointF
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.MotionEvent.*
import android.view.View
import kotlin.math.abs

object TouchAndClickListener : View.OnTouchListener {

    /** Those are factors you can change as you prefer */
    private const val touchMoveFactor = 10
    private const val touchTimeFactor = 200


    private var actionDownPoint = PointF(0f, 0f)
    private var previousPoint = PointF(0f, 0f)
    private var touchDownTime = 0L

    override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent) = when (event.action) {
        ACTION_DOWN -> PointF(event.x, event.y).let {

            actionDownPoint = it  // Store it to compare position when ACTION_UP
            previousPoint = it  // Store it to compare position when ACTION_MOVE
            touchDownTime = now() // Store it to compare time when ACTION_UP

            /* Do other stuff related to ACTION_DOWN you may whant here */

            true
        }

        ACTION_UP -> PointF(event.x, event.y).let {

            val isTouchDuration = now() - touchDownTime < touchTimeFactor  // short time should mean this is a click
            val isTouchLength = abs(it.x - actionDownPoint.x) + abs(it.y - actionDownPoint.y) < touchMoveFactor  // short length should mean this is a click

            val shouldClick = isTouchLength && isTouchDuration  // Check both

            if (shouldClick) yourView.performClick() //Previously define setOnClickListener{ } on yourView, then performClick() will call it

            /* Do other stuff related to ACTION_UP you may whant here */

            true
        }

        ACTION_MOVE -> PointF(event.x, event.y).let {

            /* Do other stuff related to ACTION_MOVE you may whant here */

            previousPoint = it
            true
        }

        else -> false // Nothing particular with other event
    }

    private fun now() = System.currentTimeMillis()
}
```

Comment: Great answer but please it should have been in java not kotlin

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Nicolas Duponchel this is how i achieved both onClick and onTouch events

```
  //Define these globally e.g in your MainActivity class
  private short touchMoveFactor = 10;
  private short touchTimeFactor = 200;
  private PointF actionDownPoint = new PointF(0f, 0f);
  private long touchDownTime = 0L;
            
             @Override
                public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                    final int action = event.getAction();
                    switch (action) {
                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                            actionDownPoint.x = event.getX();
                            actionDownPoint.y = event.getY();
                            touchDownTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            break;
                            }
                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                            //on touch released, check if the finger was still close to the point he/she clicked 
                            boolean isTouchLength = (Math.abs(event.getX() - actionDownPoint.x)+ Math.abs(event.getY() - actionDownPoint.y)) < touchMoveFactor;
                            boolean isClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - touchDownTime < touchTimeFactor;
        
                            //if it's been more than 200ms since user first touched and, the finger was close to the same place when released, consider it a click event
                            //Please note that this is a workaround :D
                            if (isTouchLength && isClickTime){ 
                               //call this method on the view, e.g ivPic.performClick();
                               performClick();}
                            break;
                            }
                     }
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

All above answer is said that we **can not** handle both `setOnTouchListener` and `setOnClickListener`.
However, I see we can **handle** both by `return false` in `setOnTouchListener`

**Example**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    button = findViewById(R.id.button)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        Log.i("TAG", "onClick")
    }

    button.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        Log.i("TAG", "onTouch " + event.action)
        false
    }
}
```

When I click at `Button`, logcat will display like

```
I/TAG: onTouch 0
I/TAG: onTouch 1
I/TAG: onClick
```

Comment: returning false from onTouch is equal to not setting onTouchListener at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Implement interface and the code here:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.send:
            switch(motionEvent.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //when the user has pressed the button
                    //do the needful here
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //when the user releases the button
                    //do the needful here
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make both  events possible in gridview,only by making return of touch listener"false" as follows,this worked for me.

```
**GridView myView = findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // ... Respond to touch events
        return false;
    }
});**
```

in this way both events can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

```
## Exact working solution for both click action and touch listener(dragging) ##

private int initialX;
private int initialY;
private float initialTouchX;
private float initialTouchY;
private float CLICK_ACTION_THRESHOLD = 0.5f;
private float startX;
private float startY;

 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.chat_head_profile_iv:
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //remember the initial position.
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    startX = event.getX();
                    startY = event.getY();
                    //get the touch location
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    float endX = event.getX();
                    float endY = event.getY();
                    if (shouldClickActionWork(startX, endX, startY, endY)) {
                        openScreen();// WE HAVE A CLICK!!
                    }
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //Calculate the X and Y coordinates of the view.
                    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);

                    //Update the layout with new X & Y coordinate
                    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mChatHeadView, params);
                    return true;
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean shouldClickActionWork(float startX, float endX, float startY, float endY) {
    float differenceX = Math.abs(startX - endX);
    float differenceY = Math.abs(startY - endY);
    if ((CLICK_ACTION_THRESHOLD > differenceX) && (CLICK_ACTION_THRESHOLD > differenceY))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: What is params ?

Answer (score 0):

In `ACTION_UP` perform `onClick` manually using condition

```
boolean shouldClick = event.eventTime - event.downTime <= 200 // compares the time with some threshold
```

So, try within `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

```
if(event.eventTime - event.downTime <= 200) { // case or when statement of action Touch listener
    view.performClick();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I knows its too late, but if someone is struggling with this for a clean solution, here it is.

These are used for measuring the time between touching and removing the finger.

```
    private long clickTime = 0;
    public static final long CLICK_TIMEOUT = 200; // 200ms
```

This my `onTouchListner`. Works like a charm

```
    private final View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = (v, event) -> {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        clickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return true;
    } else if(event.getAction() ==  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if(System.currentTimeMillis()-clickTime < Constants.CLICK_TIMEOUT)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        if(System.currentTimeMillis()-clickTime > Constants.CLICK_TIMEOUT)
        {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("" , "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(data , shadowBuilder , v , 0);
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
};
```