# Click, Press and Release event on Button

Tags: android, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

How can I detect clicked, pressed and released states of a Button. I want to perform different functions on these states. On click I want to call function1, on press I want to call function2 and on receive I want to call function3.

We can detect click state using `View.OnClickListener`. We can detect Pressed and Released states of a Button using `View.OnTouchListener` and handling `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`. I am able to detect these states individually, however, not together.

Below is code for OnCLickListener.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println(" clicked ");
        }
    });
```

Below is code for OnTouchListener.

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    System.out.println(" pressed ");
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    System.out.println(" released ");
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

When I set click and touch listeners on a Button, Click event never gets called. Instead I receive pressed and released state.

How can I handle these three states together?

EDIT:

I added the OnClickListener and OnTouchListener code I have used.

Comment: Try returning false instead of true;

Answer (score 13):

Easy since `Button` is a `View`:

```
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // Pressed
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // Released
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What about onclick event? I already explained in my question that I am able to handle press and release state separately but not with click.

Comment: What do you mean? For click there is another listener

Comment: I know for click there is OnClickListener. When I set both the listeners (OnClick and OnTouch) on the button then even if I click on the button OnCLick never gets called. Instead pressed-released gets called.

Answer (score 5):

Change the `return true;` inside `case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:` and  `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:`to `return false;` or `break;`

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159366/cant-handle-both-click-and-touch-events-simultaneously).
You can handle click manually in `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` event by

```
button.performClick();
```

Answer (score -1):

clicked event include pressed and released state,if you want to fire clicked event,put method after ACTION_UP