# How can I use OnClickListener in parent View and onTouchEvent in Child View?

Tags: android

I have a Custom Layout with a standard setOnClickListener() call.

```
setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // some click related code
            }
        });
```

In this Layout is a view that should drag horizontally.

I wrote some code and it does more or less what I want it to do:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean result = true;
    final int action = event.getAction();
    final float x = event.getRawX();
    final float y = event.getRawY();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            mInitialTouchX = x;
            mInitialTouchY = y;

            mStartX = getX();
            mStartY = getY();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            Logger.d("MOVE");
            if (direction == -1) {

            }

            final float dx = x - mInitialTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mInitialTouchY;

            mPosX = mStartX + dx;
            mPosY = mStartY + dy;

            if (Math.abs(dx) > SWYPE_MIN_TRAVEL) {
                if (Math.abs(mPosX) < maximumSwypeDistance) {
                    setTranslationX(mPosX);
                }
            }

            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Logger.d("UP");
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            Logger.d("CANCEL");
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            Logger.d("POINTER_UP");
            final float dx = x - mInitialTouchX;
            if (Math.abs(dx) < SWYPE_MIN_TRAVEL) {
                Logger.d("click");
                result = false;
            }
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The question is: How can I have both?

Edit: Well using the answer from Gunnar Karlssons event i could alter the code to perform the click manually in the `ACTION_UP` Event like this:

```
((ViewGroup) this.getParent()).performClick();
```

I can't help myself but i find this somewhat unsatisfying. I there a more elegant solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159366/cant-handle-both-click-and-touch-events-simultaneously

Comment: From Android source: onTouchEvent return "True if the event was handled, false otherwise." Try returning false.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, you can achieve this behavior. The long answer is that you need to make sure that both views get the touch events as you expect them. Depending on the exact layouts and the expected behavior you want, you can use a couple of methods:

1. You don't have to return true from onTouchEvent() - that way the touch event would go to the parent as well (just make sure that you are getting the next event).
2. Use  onInterceptTouchEvent() in the parent and detect the click by using a GestureDetector and SimpleOnGestureListener.

   ```
   GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
       @Override
       public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
           // some click related code
           return true;
       }
   };

   GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, simpleOnGestureListener);

   @Override
   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){
       gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
       return false;
   }
   ```