# Android (Xamarin) selectableItemBackground - SetBackgroundResource not working with SetImageResource

Tags: android, xamarin, imagebutton

I'm using a custom grid adapter that creates image buttons and displays them on an activity, using the method `SetImageResource()` to set the src image of the buttons.

However, when clicked, these buttons do not have the desired button click/ripple effect. After looking around, I found a couple of solutions for that, utilising a `TypedValue` with `SetBackgroundResource()`, or utilising a `TypedArray` with `SetBackgroundDrawable()`. Without the image resource, either of these methods work, but upon adding the image resource, the `selectableItemBackground` effect disappears.

The code is as following:

```
ImageButton button;

if (convertView == null)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);

    //  Grid buttons
    convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.sublayout_Menu_Button, null);

    button = convertView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.mainMenu_ImgBtn);

    button.SetMinimumHeight(Main_Menu.GRID_HEIGHT / numRows);

    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    context.Theme.ResolveAttribute(Resource.Attribute.selectableItemBackground, tv, true);
    button.SetBackgroundResource(tv.ResourceId);

    //  This code is another method that works similarly to the above                
    //int[] attrs = new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.SelectableItemBackground };
    //TypedArray ta = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
    //Drawable drawableFromTheme = ta.GetDrawable(0);
    //ta.Recycle();
    //button.SetBackgroundDrawable(drawableFromTheme);

    button.SetImageResource(buttonImages[position]);

    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            button.Click += delegate
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(Select_Hospital));
                context.StartActivity(intent);
            };
            break;

        case 1:
            button.Click += delegate
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(My_Appointments));
                context.StartActivity(intent);
            };
            break;

        case 2:
            button.Click += delegate
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(Treatment_Information));
                context.StartActivity(intent);
            };
            break;

        case 3:
            button.Click += delegate
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(Search));
                context.StartActivity(intent);
            };
            break;
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this problem? Any help would be very much appreciated!

**--EDIT--**

MyImageButton code:

```
class MyImageButton : ImageButton, IOnTouchListener
{
    private Context context;

    public MyImageButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.SetOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
        {
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)v;
            iv.SetColorFilter(new Android.Graphics.Color(context.GetColor(Resource.Color._5_grey)));
        }
        else if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)v;
            iv.ClearColorFilter();
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

AXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Dental_IT.Droid.Adapters.MyImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mainMenu_ImgBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@null" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when clicked, these buttons do not have the desired button click/ripple effect.

When click the `ImageButton`, it did has a button click/ripple effect, but it was covered by images.

You could custom a `ImageButton` to handle with the touch event, when receive a click event, you could add a `ColorFilter` on the image to implement your click/ripple effect.

Here is my code :

```
public class MyImageButton : ImageButton
{
    public float[] BT_SELECTED_DARK = new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, -50, 0, 1,
            0, 0, -50, 0, 0, 1, 0, -50, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 };

    public MyImageButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs):base(context,attrs)
    {
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
        {
            this.SetColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(BT_SELECTED_DARK));
        }
        else if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            this.ClearColorFilter();
        }
        return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

When you adding the image resource :

```
button.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.download);
button.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    Toast.MakeText(this,"Hi, I am York!",ToastLength.Short).Show();
};
```

**Effect :**

[image]

Comment: The animation does work, but the click delegate events don't work now

Comment: @Ryalis, I will update my answer when I can use my computer.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Also, would you mind explaining how the code works?

Comment: I have updated my post with the click delegates that do not work

Comment: @Ryalis, I use your code and it works fine by my side, you could debug your code to find the reason. If possible,  you could share a basic demo to reproduce this problem, troubleshooting this issue will be much easier if I have a demo.

Comment: I'm using a custom grid adapter to populate the buttons. I've tried a simple click delegate to test the functionality, but even then it does not do anything.

Comment: @Ryalis, that's strange, it should be work. Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce this  problem? I cant reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to share a basic demo at the moment. Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159366/cant-handle-both-click-and-touch-events-simultaneously) be the reason why it isn't working?

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: @Ryalis, please update your `MyImageButton`  code as my answer, then try again, : )

Comment: Thank you! That works, but only after I add `this.context = context;` in the `MyImageButton` constructor

Comment: @Ryalis, when  you implement `IOnTouchListener` interface in `MyImageButto` class, the click event was was intercepted by `OnTouchEvent` method, that's the reason why click delegates that do not work.