# How to pass a click event to RecyclerView's items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, touch, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I have an ordinary `RecyclerView`, and on top of it a transparent `View` that implements `GestureListener`, which basically have the same size of the `RecyclerView`.

The `GestureListener` will listen to scroll and fling gestures, and pass this `MotionEvent` to the `RecyclerView` underneath it.

I have already made the `RecyclerView` able to scroll and fling. However, I can't find a way to pass a click event down to the `RecyclerView`'s **items** as well.

I already know that this is because `ACTION_DOWN` is consumed in the `GestureListener`. In fact, `GestureListener` has a `onSingleTap()` method for you to override, and this method was called whenever I perform a click.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159366/cant-handle-both-click-and-touch-events-simultaneously), I tried to set an `OnTouchListener` to my itemView and listen to `ACTION_UP` events. However, the `onTouch()` method is never called.

Below is how I do it:
1. Create a callback in the transparent GestureListener

```
   @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        if (scrollDetector == null) return false;
        scrollDetector.onSingleTap(e);
        return true;
    }
```

2. Configure the callback in the activity, and pass the `MotionEvent` to the `RecyclerView`

   ```
   @Override
   public void onSingleTap(MotionEvent e) {
       mRecyclerView.onTouchEvent(e);
   }
   ```
3. Set `OnTouchListener` to the itemView in the adapter:

   ```
   itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
               v.performClick();
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
   });
   ```

Using debugger, I can see that `mRecyclerView.onTouchEvent(e)` was called; but the `onTouch()` of itemView was not called.

So... How should I correctly pass the `MotionEvent` to the itemView?

You may ask - **"Why do you place a GestureListener on top of the RecyclerView?"**
This is because I need to change the height of the `RecyclerView` when the `RecyclerView` is scrolled. However, if I do this using `RecyclerView`'s `addOnScrollListener`, the value of `dy` will fluctuate between negative and positive values, because dy is affected by its height as well. And the fluctuation will also be reflected to the UI.
Therefore I need a scroll detector that does not change its height when scrolled, and just pass the scroll and fling values to `RecyclerView` by programmatically calling `scrollBy()` and `fling()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me. I should use `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)` instead of `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)`.

However, this is not enough.
Simply calling `dispatchTouchEvent(e)` using the MotionEvent from GestureListener is not working, because that `e` is an `ACTION_UP` event.

To simulate a click, you need both `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`.

And itemView does not need to set `OnTouchListener` since you have already simulate

Code:

```
        @Override
        public void onSingleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            long upTime = downTime + 100;
            MotionEvent downEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, downTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    e.getX(), e.getY(), 0);
            mRecyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(downEvent);
            MotionEvent upEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(upTime, upTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                    e.getX(), e.getY(), 0);
            mRecyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(upEvent);
            downEvent.recycle();
            upEvent.recycle();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should known that recyclerview's event.If recyclerview can move when you scroll views,it will call onInterceptTouchEvent() and return true to intercept event.So you can't get the ACTION_MOVE event.Maybe you should rewrite the recyclerview's onInterceptTouchEvent() and return false. Then you can get all the event in your itemView's methods.